# How to deploy Node.JS application on Apache server?

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, proxypass

I am developing node.js application and wants to deploy on apache server and run with https url only.

There is following url scheme I would like to configure on server.

https://example.com runs node js application on **1000** port from **/home/main/public_html/** directory.
https://example.com:1335 runs node js application from **/home/main/public_html/stagging/** directory.
https://example.com:4234 runs node js application from **/home/main/public_html/development/** directory.

I want to achieve this type of url output from server.

I tried following way to achieve this but it display just directory listing only. I want to execute nodejs application.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off

    #Executes code from main directory
    <Proxy https://whizbite.com:1000>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        ProxyPreserveHost off
        ProxyPass https://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8080/
    </Proxy>

    #Executes code from staging directory
    <Proxy https://whizbite.com:1335>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        ProxyPreserveHost off
        ProxyPass https://localhost:8080/staging/
        ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8080/staging/
    </Proxy>

    #Executes code from development directory
    <Proxy https://whizbite.com:4234>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        ProxyPreserveHost off
        ProxyPass https://localhost:8080/development/
        ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8080/development/
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

I really don't know how to achieve above url scheme by modification of apache configuration.

Comment: Is your node.js server running?

Comment: yes, my nodejs server is running by pm2 module.